# What is the efficiency of current airlock designs

Tags: airlock

I know that current airlocks in space cannot be 100% efficient. There must be some loss in atmosphere or in the very least a certain amount of power consumption.

Can someone find statistics that detail:

1) the least amount of atmosphere lost by current airlock designs in operation in space.

2) The amount of power consumed in depressurizing the above airlock model.

3) The time it takes to depressurize and pressurize the airlock.

Comment: The ISS airlock, initially at 14.7 psi, pumps down into the ISS general volume until the airlock is at a low pressure (I think around 5 psi). The residual gas is wasted into space.  I'm not interested enough to research the details of your other questions but perhaps this will get you started.

Comment: The design of [the first airlock implemented for the ISS (quest joint airlock)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quest_Joint_Airlock) would be a good place to start too, perhaps looking at the other 3 airlocks installed after that first one would be good too. There are multiple different designs implemented, AFAIK.